# Is there any way to know if a message is received in an iOS Application?

Tags: ios

We are able to find out if a call is ringing , like this any way to notify when a text message is received??

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way of knowing if message was received in iOS, since it enters the system in the form of a push notification from the messages app. And **Push Notifications** fired by any app expect yours cannot be detected, not even with **NotificationCenter** observers... 
But you can detect that your app will resign active after a possible SMS(or an incoming phone call) with `applicationWillResignActive()` method from your AppDelegate. According to Apple:

> Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive
>   state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions
>   (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits
>   the application and it begins the transition to the background state. 
>   Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle
>   down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the
>   game.

But there is no way to know for sure if this was fired by a received SMS.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I'm trying to replicate the same functionality as that of cell control... They hides all the notifications when they are received in the device.

Comment: also, is there any private api's to do so?

Comment: I do not know more about this subject, google it and if there is any API you will find it